# Rebuilding Database function in Playstation 3.

Tags: ps3, hard-drive

I been having some problems with the PS3 lately. For instance, I was re playing Dark Souls and when I was in Undead Burg the assets didn't load correctly so it kinda was impossible to play. Since it was all grey, I could see the enemies and could walk, just couln't see where. After I started to notice that installing games and loading games was taking longer, I install bioshock infinite and took almost 3 hours. I don't remember that game did took that much the first time I install it. So, my question is. What exactly does "Rebuild Database"? Is kinda like defragmentation? could it help me? Also, does this delete save games/games/dlc's or anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly a defrag, but it may solve the types of issues you're having nonetheless. From the [PS3 Developer Wiki](http://www.psdevwiki.com/ps3/Recovery_Menu#4._Rebuild_Database) (and probably one of the older, no-longer-existent official support pages, given that this exact same text shows up in multiple places through a Google search):

> This will rewrite corrupted files within the database, potentially eliminating future issues. This feature should not erase any of your saved data or settings (except some PSN account information). 
>   Deletes messages, playlists, changes made on "Information" screens, trimming information for pictures in "Photo", video thumbnails, video playback history and video resume information.

The process can take a pretty long time, and will likely sign you out of PSN, so make sure to log back in after it's done.